# How to create a LinkedIn page

Tags: linkedin-api

I am new to LinkedIn, but I want to know how to create a LinkedIn page via API or whatever ways that I can. So I need all information that you can give me.

Comment: If you've created your resume in a word document already you can import that on the right and it will do it all for you. Is this what you wanted? Or are you trying to integrate it from a website?

Comment: "Or whatever ways that can"? Are you asking for any possible means of creating a linkedIn page? Have you read their help on the site?

Comment: hmm. I mean I'm still confused. And I don't know much about LinkedIn. And yes I haven't read all of their help yet, but I did read some. N those were no helps at all.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to integrate it from a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is to create or edit your profile via the LinkedIn API, then this will not be possible. As per this link, they do not allow profile editing as part of the api: http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/3125

Comment: Thanks you for this info. However, I want to know if I can create or edit a page via API. Is this possible?

Comment: If you click on the details link for any one of the sections on the API page (http://developer.linkedin.com/apis), it gives you a description of exactly what the API allows. For the most part its a largely read-only search type api. And I see no indication that you can create or edit pages.